# Monitor Fax with C#

Tags: c#, windows, service, fax

I am trying to create a small software with C# that can be able to monitor the receive and send faxes for example: time,user etc.. I have search in google and find about FAXCOMEXLib and FAXCOMLib but I didn't find any good examples for C# only for VB. Also I was thinking somehow use the windows fax service but also I didn't find anything. Can anyone provide me a sample code for C# or a better way to do this?
p.s: I want only to monitor not even send from the software

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at Microsoft's TAPI, or Telephony API.  This is a COM API that comes with Windows and makes it really simply to send or receive faxes, as well as other telephone-related activities (answering a phone, taking voicemail messsages, etc).  A great place to start is the TAPI quick start application ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms734257(v=vs.85).aspx ).

Comment: Is C++ not C# and is more for phone calls as i can see on the link you provided..

Comment: While the TAPI library itself is written in C++, it exposes COM objects that you can use in managed languages such as C#.  This link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10994/TAPI-Application-development-using-C-NET#xx1473051xx is a great example of using TAPI with C#, and even has a little bit about fax / data mode.  While it is true that much of the TAPI library exists to support some of the more complicated telephony features, fax is definitely a core feature.  As a matter of fact, Microsoft uses the TAPI library in the Windows Fax Server that ships with most modern versions of Windows.